# <apex:outputField> on URL-field renders Popup - blocked in Chrome

Tags: visualforce, lightning, bug, popup, chrome

In a Visualforce page (embedded into Page Layout sections) I reference a custom object with an URL field using:

```
<apex:outputField value="{!record.SupportLink__c}"/>
```

When clicking the link rendered by the `apex:outputField`, Chrome blocks it as a popup. Both in Lightning and in Classic. In Classic it also happens when opening the link from the native record page (no Visualforce involved) itself.

Chrome is listed as a *supported browser without any limitations* both for Classic (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=getstart_browser_aloha.htm&type=5) and Lightning (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=getstart_browsers_sfx.htm&type=5). With this in mind, I'd expect this to work without any problems.

- **What can I do to prevent the popups here?**
- **Is there any official documentation that states this behaviour so I could show it to my customers?**